# UILocalNotification not working anymore?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've been using a UILocalNotification in my iPad App & it worked for some time until recently.

I can't produce any notifications at all, no matter what I try. Here's my last attempt:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
    NSDate *dateToFire = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:300]; // 5 minutes
    [localNotification setFireDate:dateToFire];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Incoming Local Notification" ];
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    [localNotification setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];             
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    [localNotification release];
    }
```

My iPad is set to Auto-Lock=2minutes.

Shouldn't there be a notification after 5 minutes considering the code above?

Answer (score 4):

Yes that should work. Keep in mind that local notification (as well as push notification) will not be shown if your application is currently open.

If your app is open you need to look for call of

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

in your app delegate.

Comment: By 'open' you mean the iPad did not Auto-Lock and the application is running ? Because that's how I tested it: Setting the notification to 5mins in the future. The iPad got Auto-locked after 2 minutes.

Comment: You can intercept the local notification here and display an alert view if you want the alert to be shown while the app is open.

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification does work when my app is not open. But the code posted above does not work. I don't get it. There is another thing I'm wondering about: When logging the firedate property it is one hour in the past.

Comment: I've got a similar issue, application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification has stops been called after few success calls. Application is in foreground   and Notification is pushed. What can be cause of the issue? Thanks

Comment: I've found a cause of issue, for debug purpose I used to create notifications very often, but there is limit for 64 scheduled notifications for Application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when updating from iOS4 to 5 Apple disables notifications for Apps that already have been installed under 4. If you go to Settings -> Notifications you can reenable them. That solves the problem.